# Need bundle with javax.persistence on OSGi

Tags: jpa, osgi, apache-servicemix

I get this error when I try to install my bundle in Servicemix:

```
Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
Unable to start bundle 179: Unresolved constraint in bundle de.edigrid.edigrid-servicemix-util [179]: Unable to resolve 179.0: missing requirement [179.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)
```

Can anybody tell me if is there a standard jar file, OSGi compliant, that exports javax.persistence package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the jpa feature. If this feature is not available in your servicemix version then try:

```
install -s mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLinks has a bundle, it's included in their download: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.2/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.zip

Alternatively you can also get the same bundle from the Amdatu Dependencies repository: https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/amdatu-repository/src/53bb0dd92bcf005da5a6937c2034d366e9f21365/dependencies/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar?at=master#